# Быстрая генерация случайных строк в Qt

Tags: qt

```
QString GetRandomString() const
{
   const QString     
   possibleCharacters("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
   const int randomStringLength = 12; // assuming you want random strings of 12 characters

   QString randomString;
   for(int i=0; i<randomStringLength; ++i)
   {
       int index = qrand() % possibleCharacters.length();
       QChar nextChar = possibleCharacters.at(index);
       randomString.append(nextChar);
   }
   return randomString;
}
```

Если делать так, то при генерации строки чаще чем 1 раз в миллисекунду, строки начинают повторяться. Какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: А вы саму qrand проверяли, на сколько случайные числа она дает, каково распределение и нет ли повтора гаммы (выдаваемых значений) скажем за 1 млн вызовов.

Comment: По крайней мере я сталкивался с тем, что младший байт выдаваемый стандартным алгоритмом randU (можно найти википедии) довольно быстро начинает повторятся. Решается операцией XOR всех 4х байт выдаваемых этой функцией между собой. тогда можно ожидать повтора гаммы через примерно 130млн знаков

Answer (score 1):

В Windows `QtGlobal::qrand()` просто вызывает стандартную функцию `rand()` из `cstdlib`. Похоже, что её конкретная реализация использует каким-то образом системное время, поэтому возвращаемое значение и не меняется, если с точки зрения функции время не изменилось. В качестве решения проблемы можно использовать собственный генератор псевдослучайных чисел, например, [линейно-конгруэнтный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Comment: Интересно чем инициализировать последовательность. rand наверняка использует что то схожее, проблема в начальном значении. Его просто надо сохранять от запуска к запуску.

Comment: @Mike Интересно было бы узнать какой компилятор у ТС.